# Architecture's ViewModel and observe

Tags: android, mvvm

In the [Google's example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) `ViewModels` changes are observed using

```
model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
  // update UI
});
```

The `--> {}` pattern is a Java 8 lambda-functions feature. `users` is undefined in this case. Also Studio shows mismatch error, since `Observer<your_type>` is expected as the 2nd parameter.

According to the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html):

> void  observe(LifecycleOwner owner, Observer observer)
>   Adds the given observer to the observers list within the lifespan of the given owner.

So the code supposed to be something like:

```
class Observer FooObserver() {
  @Override
  public function onChanged(...
}
..
fooObserver = new FooObserver(..
..
model.getUsers().observe(this, fooObserver);
```

---

**Question:**

Is this supposed to be some kind of abstract example or do this shortcut code really suppose to replace `Observer` usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a short form for inner observer implementation.

So this

```
model.getUsers().observe(this, users -> {
// update UI
});
```

Is equal to this

```
model.getUsers().observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(User user) {

    }
});
```

You can integrate lambda expressions and some of the other java8 features into your projects using [Retrolambda.](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)